# the usage of addPyFile in pyspark is ambiguous

Tags: pyspark

There is a `addPyFile` method in pyspark, But I don't know how to use it and its usage on the net is very few. I think the `addPyFile` can pass python files to spark nodes, and I tested it:

```
sc.addPyFile("/sparkLearning/tools/redis_util.py")
rdd = sc.parallelize([('a', 10), ('b', 20), ('c', 30)])

def map_1(row):
    redis_util = redis_util.RedisUtil()
    k = row[0]
    v = row[1]
    redis_util.set(name=k, value=v)
rdd.map(map_1).collect()
```

It went wrong: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'redis_util' referenced before assignment`, But how can I get the usage of `addPyFile`?

Comment: did you import `redis_util`?

Comment: I have add the file using addPyFile, do I need import it again?

Comment: can you provide the whole error message?